# Error while running update query for access database

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=" + Application.StartupPath + "/shoping mall.mdb");
                con.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("update RecordofItems set RecordofItems.Bill_no = " + textBox1.Text + ", RecordofItems.Received_from = '" + textBox62.Text + "', RecordofItems.Item_Code = " + textBox2.Text + ", RecordofItems.Quantity = " + textBox32.Text + ", RecordofItems.Sale_Rate = " + textBox47.Text + " where Item_Name = '" + textBox17.Text + "'", con);
                int x = 0;
                x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (x > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("record deleted" + x);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("no record exixt");
                }
                con.Close();
```

I want to update selected columns in my "RecordofItems" table that has 10 columns but I want to update only 6 selected columns, when I run the query it shows error "no value for one or more required paremeter" What to do ? please help me as soon as you can.

Comment: are you sure columns names are correct ? by the way you should be using command parameters.

Answer (score 0):

the error `No value given for one or more required parameters` usually comes when you have misplaced single quote.

try these two.

1. try assigning your numerical db columns a numerical value viz update your query with these:

   ```
   RecordofItems.Bill_no = " + Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + ",  
   RecordofItems.Item_Code = " + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) + ",    
   RecordofItems.Quantity = " + Convert.ToInt32(textBox32.Text) + ",     
   RecordofItems.Sale_Rate = " + Convert.ToInt32(textBox47.Text) +
   ```

   or use whatever suitable numerical converter applies to your columns.
2. one of your text fields might have a single quote in it, so try replacing/updating your text fields like this:

   ```
   RecordofItems.Received_from = '" + textBox62.Text.Replace("'","''") + "',
   ```

so basically, replace single quote with two single quotes.

see if these solve your issue.

Also, do note, never create your sql query by concatenating textboxes(strings). use command parameters. they will save you from sql injection.